# mongodb set a nested object value

Tags: mongodb, nested

Here is my problem :
I need to set a nested value using the following command :

```
db.getCollection('user').
updateOne(
{ username: 'adh3', 'pf.acc.accnbr': 1234 } 
, {
        "$set": {
                "pf.acc.$.cyc.0": {
                        "cycid": 1498894685,
                        "name": "QPT262017_S3",
                        "startdate": "2017-06-27T09:50",
                        "enddate": "2017-09-25T09:50",
                        "age": 99,
                        "status": "TEST",
                        "active": true,
                        "det.1": 
                           {
                                "createDate": "2017-06-27T09:50",
                                "moment": "TEST",
                                "progress": 0,
                                "age": 0,
                                "dcycid": 1498557047
                           }

                }
        }
})
```

And here is my collection schema :

```
user : {
     username: string,
     pf : {
           pfid: number
           acc : [ {
                accnbr: number,
                cyc : [ {
                   cycid: number,
                   name: string,
                   ...
                   det : [ {
                       dcycid: number,
                       ...
                   } ]
                } ]
           } ]
     }
}
```

The error I got is the following :

```
the pf.acc.0.cyc.0.det.1 is not a valid for storage
```

Any idea how should I solve my query ?

Comment: Apparently we cannot say this enough. "Do not nest arrays within arrays". You must have seen that stated at least once to even be attempting such an update and using absolute indexes. There is absolutely no need to nest arrays, as the reasons everyone seems to think gives them an advantage, we end up explaining why it actually does not. Over and over again.

Comment: No there is not. Already explained that "absolute indexes" are not a solution. And yet you still persist. **OR** To phrase that differently and more accurately is. DO NOT NEST ARRAYS. Use "attributes" on an array to represent the things "you think" are nested keys. Nested keys just do not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by dividing the query into 2 parts:

1. Concerning the cyc part.
2. Concerning the det part.

Comment: To make this into something that is at least a passable answer, you should [edit] in the actual code that you used.